# calender in php use in online admission form

Tags: php

I've created a an "online_admission_form.php" for a clients website and a part of the form requires the user to enter a date (for date of birth), I was thinking that instead of typing the date in they could click an icon and have a little calendar appear to allow them to select a date..Also i want to store the selected date in a php varaible.
Important Note:- I cant use java script or any other language only i can use PHP because i this php page is of my Final project of Master degree of Compuer science.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
please help...
every responce will be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible, but not a good idea, to implement a calendar in only PHP/HTML.

Comment: Hell Jahangri, http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ it will help

Comment: You won't get a *popup calendar* without Javascript. A pure HTML/PHP calendar is possible, but it won't just "appear". Also, since this is your master degree, you should be working out the details.

Comment: You are going to have a really hard time finding a suitable non-javascript option for a calendar. I also don't know why you would think it would be inappropriate to use javascript on such a project. Real world applications NEED both server-side and client-side scripting, so if this isn't a constraint specifically placed on you, I would remove it. I am actually more shocked that you can use PHP for a master's project than not be being able to use javascript (if that is really the case).

Comment: 1. he asks for a way to select the date rather than typing it. ie html5 date. 

2. you can make a calendar that does not only rely on JS.

Comment: Try this, hope it will work, http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php

Answer (score 0):

the beauty of HTML5:

```
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

the when you pass this to your php form just use

```
$date = $_POST['bday'];
```

As to all who recommended jquery, there is absolutely no point in implementing an entire library when w3 did the work for us.

Comment: Bundles of thanks dear Mike Brant ! just before few minutes i called my supervisor, first he did't allow me to use java script in my project but when i told him that it is difficult and also not match with todays standard then he said, "ok you can use java script" so dear Mike Brant can you please tell me the complete code for this calender that i want to use for selecting Date Of Birth in my online_admission_form.php page and also tell me how can i store that selected date in php variable, that php variable further i will use in INSERT QUERY of mysql.

Comment: @JahangirKhattak But on that note, shy from rewritting a calendar program by hand (which im currently doing), you may aswell just use google calendar